# how to Monitor all the events in website using NODEJS backend?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, web

capturing all the input changes and page events in my web application with Nodejs backend application.

How the site watcher should be designed for the site?

Are there any possibilities to use effective channel in clientSide to monitor the client side actions?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/users/5723736/khaled-saleh : "So, you wanna monitor the user clicks, hovers for instance in the clientSide? or you wanna monitor the Http requests/IO operations?"

Comment: I want to keep track all the user clicks and I/O operations and that has to be stored in server. By the time I can't post all the single activities to server all the small actions. Give me suggestion to achieve this in Angular and React application.